# Navigation with nested frames

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation

Here is a simplified example of my problem situation.

MainPage.xaml

```
<page
    ...
    xmlns:helpers="using:MyNamespace.Helpers"
    xmlns:views="using:MyNamespace.Views"
    ...>

    <NavigationView Name="MainNav"
                    PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                    ...>
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="OtherPage"
                                helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:OtherPage">
                </NavigationViewItem>
                ... other NavigationViewItem's...
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame Name="MainFrame".../>   
</page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MainNav.ItemInvoked += Navigate.NavView_ItemInvoked;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

OtherPage.xaml - In views folder

```
<page
    ...
    xmlns:helpers="using:MyNamespace.Helpers"
    xmlns:views="using:MyNamespace.Views"
    ...>

    <NavigationView Name="OtherNav"
                    PaneDisplayMode="Top"
                    ...>
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Other Page"
                                helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:OtherPage_1">
                </NavigationViewItem>
                ... other NavigationViewItem's...
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame Name="OtherFrame".../>   
</page>
```

OtherPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Views
{
    public sealed partial class OtherPage : Page
    {
        public OtherPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            OtherNav.ItemInvoked += Navigate.NavView_ItemInvoked;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Navigate.cs - in Services folder

```
namespace MyNamespace.Services
{
    static class Navigate
    {
        public static void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            \\ do some navigation logic
            ...
            private _frame = ???;
            ...

            _frame.Navigate(_page, null, transitionInfo);
        }
```

Ok so after all that example code, here is my problem. In the `NavView_ItemInvoked` event handler, I need to be able to set `_frame` depending on the `NavigationViewItem` being invoked; either to `MainFrame` or `OtherFrame`.

Note: I'm probably going to move away from nested frames in my app, but I first want to figure this out because I don't like to waste a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trigger the ItemInvoked event,you can get NavigationView instance from it.NavigationView has a **Content** property,it actually represents the Frame in the currently triggered navigationView.So you can get MainFrame or OtherFrame by **Frame.name**.

```
static class MyNavigate
    {​
        public static void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)​
        {​
            Frame currentFrame = sender.Content as Frame;​
            String name = currentFrame.Name;​
            if (name == "OtherFrame")​
            {​
                currentFrame.Navigate(.......);​
            }​
            else {​
                currentFrame.Navigate(.......);​
            }​
        }​
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Faywang. I had it in my head that the frame would have been contained by Content, like `sender.Content.myFrame`. Obviously, I was wrong.